# Find the CDF of $Z=\{X_1+X_2, X_1<X_3\}$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $X_1, X_2$ and $X_3$ be three independent exponential random variables. The PDF and CDF of $X_i$ with parameter $\beta_i$ are 
$$
f_{X_i}(x_i)=\beta_i e^{-\beta_i x_i}
$$

$$
F_{X_i}(x_i)=1-e^{-\beta_i x_i}
$$

What is the CDF of random variable $Z$ define the sum of $X_1$ and $X_2$ where $X_1$ is less then $X_3$.
$$Z=\{X_1+X_2, X_1<X_3\}$$.

Thanks.

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried?

Comment: I want to find the probability that $X_1+X_2\leq z$ where $X_1$ is upper bound or less then another random variable $X_3$.

Comment: Yes, I can see that. Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: I tride $$\int_{x_3=0}^{\infty}\int_{x_2=0}^{x_3}\left(\int_{x_2=0}^{z-x_1}f_{X_2}(x_2) dx_2\right)f_{X_1}(x_1) dx_1f_{X_3}(x_3) dx_2.$$

Comment: I stuck in the last integral. And i think we need to take all possible cases

Comment: I couldn't continue from here because I think we need to take into account all possible

Comment: I try the case $P\{X_2\leq z-X_1,X_1<X_3\}$. But I think we need to take the two cases $P\{X_1\leq z-X_2<X_3\}$+$P\{X_1<X_3<z-X_2\}$$?